# OAuth 2 Enforcement in Bluemix API Management

Tags: oauth-2.0, ibm-cloud, ibm-api-management

I am trying to enforce OAuth 2 in Bluemix for a suite of microservices via API Management. Am I right in the assumption that the API Management service will always act as an OAuth 2 Authorization Provider as opposed to only checking the validity of access tokens as an enforcement gateway? The latter would be what I really want to have though.

Ideally I would like to specify my own OAuth Provider Implementation with the means to issue, validate and revoke access tokens. Then having the API Management service as a proxy for my services ensuring that requests coming in carry a valid token.

Reading the documentation I am struggling to understand how the API Management was designed. Could somebody point me to the direction I am looking for, or alternatively help me to understand what the API management's role in the OAuth Flows, listed in the Security Schemes, is?

Thanks.